# Microsoft.ReportingService.Interface not found even with Reporting Server installed

Tags: reporting-services, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to compile an old project for my company, which uses Microsoft SQL Server 2005 as the database. Within the project, one part is to reference Microsoft.ReportingService.Interface. However, upon compilation, the compiler said it cannot be found.

My machine (a virtual one, anyway) is a Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit) Standard version, with Microsoft SQL Server 2005 (64-bit) installed (along with 64-bit SQL 2008 and 2008 R2). All 3 SQL Server versions got everything installed (SQL Server, SSRS, SSAS, SSIS, and all misc stuff). However, when I look at the GAC, only the one with SQL 2008 was there (version 10), and the one for SQL 2005 is not there. Order of installation is SQL 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2.

Does anyone know whether I will have to reinstall SQL 2005, or if there is any other way to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The DLL should be in the ReportServer/bin directory of the Reporting Services 2005 installation.  Have you done a search on the machine for all Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out by myself... by searching the installation folder, the DLL is in there, but it was not registered to the GAC. Simply installing the DLL to the GAC directly solves the problem.